# Change a BindingSource items, silently

Tags: c#, winforms, events, binding, bindingsource

**[Updated]**

I have a `BindingSource` object that contains a list of some objects(a `BindingList<T>` used as source of `BindingSource`, and `<T>` implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`), Is there any way to insert or remove some objects to the `BindingSource`, pragmatically, that does not cause  raising `ListChanged` event?

e.g:
when I write this code:

```
myBindingSource.Insert(5,someObject);
```

I does not want the `ListChanged` event raise.

Comment: We need more information, are you using Observablecollections?

Comment: @Alexandre: No, I used a BindingList<T> as source of BindingSource

Comment: Can you show us some code, please?

Comment: You could catch the event and prevent it from bubbling by marking event.Handled = true. That said I would re-examine logic to see if I can avoid this entirely.

Comment: @DrewR : But i want prevent raising this event only and only when the list change pragmatically.

Comment: Set some flag or bind an event handler only when changing the list in that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `RaiseListChangedEvents` property to allow raising the event `ListChanged` or not:

```
myBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
myBindingSource.Insert(5,someObject);
myBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
```